# Can't get windows username correctly when deployed to IIS .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a webapp and I deploy it on IIS. In app, I am getting the username of current user. I get the username with `Environment.UserName`. When I deploy it to IIS, it is giving me the site's name (application pool name) as the username. I enabled the windows authentication and disabled the anonymous authentication on IIS. What would be the problem and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Your application *does* run under the pool account so that's what `Environment.UserName` returns. That's not specific to .NET 6, that's how ASP.NET always worked, all the way back to 2002. To get the authenticated user's name you need to use the controller's `User` property or `HttpContext.User`. Both return a `ClaimsPrincipal` object

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;   this is also null.

Comment: `IHttpContextAccessor` is used to access the current HttpContext. If you create a new orphan instance there's no context to access. The *interface* should be passed as a dependency to any class that needs it, not created explicitly